# ubuntu 20.04 lts wifi not working at all rtl8812au

Tags: drivers, wireless, 20.04

After a fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04

The WiFi option is not available in the desktop environment Settings -> Network panel. I only see Ethernet.

This driver was working on Ubuntu 19.04, but not on 20.04

https://github.com/abperiasamy/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux

After installing the driver and re-starting there is still no WiFi options nor icons.

Also, tried a few various other flavors of the drivers like

https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8812au

Currently installed via:

`sudo apt install rtl8812au-dkms`

Then did a reboot. Still no WiFi.

```
~$ dkms status
rtl8812au, 4.3.8.12175.20140902+dfsg, 5.4.0-26-generic, x86_64: installed
```

```
~$ lsmod | grep realtek
snd_hda_codec_realtek   118784  1
snd_hda_codec_generic    81920  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
ledtrig_audio          16384  2 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hda_codec         131072  4 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hda_core           90112  5 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd                    90112  37 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_seq,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_intel,snd_usb_audio,snd_usbmidi_lib,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_timer,snd_compress,snd_soc_core,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi
```

This shows the USB WiFi device.

```
~$ lsusb | grep Realtek
Bus 007 Device 002: ID 0bda:b812 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 802.11ac NIC
```

Shows the Ethernet adapter:

```
~$ ip link show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: enp4s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether d0:50:99:7a:52:94 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

```
~$ nmcli device status
DEVICE  TYPE      STATE      CONNECTION         
enp4s0  ethernet  connected  Wired connection 1 
lo      loopback  unmanaged  --
```

Is there anything specific that one should try to get this to work?

Thanks

Comment: Any errors in dmesg/syslog?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/YdpWJcmu

Looks related:
`NetworkManager[756]: <warn>  [1587689336.1131] Error: failed to open /run/network/ifstate`

Comment: try `grep -i rtl` - you probably only want to see what that driver is outputting?

Comment: $ cat /var/log/syslog | grep -i rtl


$ dmesg | grep -i rtl


Returns nothing.

Comment: The correct driver for your device is not rtl8812au. It is 88x2bu. I am voting to close as a duplicate. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: I would like to know who you know that?

This is the device: https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B07FGX8LBF/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_search_asin_title?ie=UTF8&psc=1

Linux docs point to: https://github.com/abperiasamy/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux

I am certain that these worked on Ubuntu 19.

Just installed the rtl88x2bu drivers ran a reboot and it is still the same issue.

```
$ dkms status
rtl88x2bu, 5.3.1, 5.4.0-26-generic, x86_64: installed
```

Comment: You can go through the source of the driver - I think usb_intf.c or something, and the driver matches the usb Manufacturer and device ID. In your case, it's 0bda:b812. Maybe it worked on 1910 because you had a different driver installed as well