# Ubuntu 20.04 wifi not working on Mac

Tags: drivers, wireless, 20.04

I used ubuntu 16.04 and 18.04 and they were able to work with wifi after following below guides:

- [Ubuntu 20.04 Ethernet and WiFi not
  working](https://askubuntu.com/q/1235683/44354)
- [Ubuntu 20.04 lts
  wifi not working at all rtl8812au[duplicate]](https://askubuntu.com/q/1230025/44354)
- [Wifi adapter not
  found, rtl8821ce no longer working
  [18.04]](https://askubuntu.com/q/1214834/44354)
- [How to install Wi-Fi
  driver for Realtek RTL8821CE on Ubuntu 18.04?
  [duplicate]](https://askubuntu.com/q/1071299/44354)

This time with Ubuntu 20.04, none of above works.

Output of command `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list`  as below:

```
02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries NetXtreme BCM57765 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe [14e4:16b4] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries NetXtreme BCM57765 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe [14e4:16b4]
    Kernel driver in use: tg3
    Kernel modules: tg3
02:00.1 SD Host controller [0805]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM57765/57785 SDXC/MMC Card Reader [14e4:16bc] (rev 10)
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

I wonder why Ubuntu does not fix this issue.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: Your linked "guides" are completely unrelated. They are all about different hardware that is unlikely to be installed in your Mac. They seem to be random links about Wi-Fi. The first one is an unanswered question, the second about a USB dongle, etc.

Comment: @Pilot6 , thanks for response. I have updated the answer

Comment: I don't see any build-in PCI devices. The Wi-Fi adapter may be disabled in BIOS or broken.

Comment: Is the correct (nonfree) firmware for the Broadcom NIC installed?

Comment: Can `iwconfig` use your wifi interface? Try executing this on terminal: `iwlist wlan0 scan` . Replace wlan0 with your wifi interface.